# How to call a service via service channel

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, model-view-controller

I am trying to call a service via a  service channel. My `BeginGet()` call is working fine but `EndGet()` is giving casting error as below. Can someone please tell what am I doing wrong?

> Error:  Unable to cast object of type 'Service.AddressServiceClient'
>   to type 'ServiceClient`1[IAddressServiceChannel]'.

My Code:

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginGet(long id)
 {
        var service = GetClient();  
        IAsyncResult handle = service.BeginGetAddress(id);
        return handle;
 }

 private Service.AddressServiceClient GetClient()
 {
        var client = new Service.AddressServiceClient();
        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Clear();
        client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(SetCred()); // setting custom credentials

        return client;
  }

public  EndGet(IAsyncResult handle)
{
     handle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

     //ServiceClient is a class which implements IDisposable

     ***// getting runtime exception at following line***
     using (var channel = (ServiceClient<Service.IServiceChannel>)handle.AsyncState) 
     {
            return channel.Client.EndGetAddress(handle)
     }
 }
```

I did try to change `EndGet()` as follows, but I am getting a compilation error:

```
public  EndGet(IAsyncResult handle)
{
     handle.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

     ***// get compilation error AddressServiceClient is a type, which is not valid in given context*** 
     using (var channel = <Service.AddressServiceClient> handle.AsyncState)
        {
              return channel.Client.EndGetAddress(handle)
        }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for an unclear title but stack overflow kept giving me 'it looks like spam message for title'.

Comment: `<>` is not valid syntax for casting, use `()`. such as `using( var channel = (Service.AddressServiceClient) handle.AsyncState`)